# How is ASP.NET faster than Node.js knowing that ASP.NET is blocking and synchronous?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, web-development-server

I was going through the ASP.NET official website and came across this photo

[image]

According to me, Node js should be faster as it is non blocking and asynchronous in nature but after looking at the photo it seems ASP.NET is the fastest one.
Could somebody explain this?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07dIm.jpg

Comment: Do you generally believe charts like this from a commercial vendor with a stake in the outcome?  Do you understand exactly what type of test this test represents and whether that best represents what your server will do?  It's likely we could develop a server test that would make any one of these three look like the best choice by tweaking the test to line up with the strengths of one particular platform and not applying any optimizations to the other platforms.

Comment: For example, if you add some CPU intensive work to the test response handler (say calc a bunch of primes) a multi-threaded server platform will do better than node.js without clustering node.js or adding worker processes to involve more CPUs.  But, that's a relatively simple optimization to add to node.js if needed.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary: Who told you ASP.NET is blocking and synchronous?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic for this site. (And I do mean that I'm not sure.) It is about a programming tool/language, but it seems like it would also require (potentially) an overly detailed answer, and is merely seeking to verify the performance of the particular tool (.NET) and possibly invites a discussion about how it markets itself.